# Part of Text cut(hidden) in JFace ComboBoxCellEditor

Tags: eclipse, combobox, swt, jface

I have an issue with jface ComboBoxCellEditor that part of the text is cut like the image below.

[image: comboBox text cut]

I'm using these plugins,

org.eclipse.swt_3.106.1.v20170926-0519.jar org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64_3.106.1.v20170926-0519.jar org.eclipse.jface_3.13.1.v20170810-0135.jar

This issue only happens on Windows, not on UBUNTU, so it seems to be a bug of SWT or jface. I filed a bug report against Eclipse SWT [533282](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=533282), but haven't got a response yet. If any of you know about this issue and there's a workaround for this, that will be greatly useful for me.

```java
import org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.*;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.*;

class CyTableComboBug extends Dialog
{
    int mComboIndex;  
    String[] mComboItems = new String[] { "Combo Item 1 long string",   
        "Combo Item 2" };   

    public CyTableComboBug(Shell parentShell)  
    {  
        super(parentShell);  
    }  

    @Override
    protected Control createDialogArea(final Composite parent)
    {
        final Composite container = 
            (Composite) super.createDialogArea(parent);

        TableViewer viewer = new TableViewer(container,  
            SWT.MULTI | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL |   
            SWT.FULL_SELECTION | SWT.BORDER);

        TableViewerColumn column = new TableViewerColumn(viewer, SWT.NONE);
        column.getColumn().setText("Column 1");
        column.setLabelProvider(new Column1LabelProvider());
        column.setEditingSupport(new Column1EditingSupport(viewer));

        viewer.setContentProvider(new ArrayContentProvider());
        viewer.setInput(new Integer[] { 0 });

        column.getColumn().pack();

        Table table = viewer.getTable();
        table.setHeaderVisible(true);
        table.setLinesVisible(true);

        return container;
    }

    private class Column1LabelProvider extends ColumnLabelProvider
    {
        @Override
        public String getText(Object element)
        {
            return mComboItems[mComboIndex];
        }
    }

    class Column1EditingSupport extends EditingSupport
    {
        protected ComboBoxCellEditor mEditor;

        public Column1EditingSupport(TableViewer viewer)
        {
            super(viewer);
            mEditor = new ComboBoxCellEditor(  
                viewer.getTable(), mComboItems,  
                SWT.READ_ONLY | SWT.BORDER);  

            mEditor.setActivationStyle(  
                ComboBoxCellEditor.DROP_DOWN_ON_MOUSE_ACTIVATION);
        }

        @Override
        protected boolean canEdit(final Object element)
        {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        protected CellEditor getCellEditor(final Object element)
        {
            return mEditor;
        }

        @Override
        protected Object getValue(final Object element)
        {
            return mComboIndex;
        }

        @Override
        protected void setValue(final Object element, final Object value)
        {
            mComboIndex = (int) value;
        }
    }
}
```